# Sliding dovetail expansion

Tags: dovetail

I am making a bookshelf. There are going to be 3 fixed shelves attached with sliding dovetails. The top shelf is 1/4 inch from the top of the side. The bottom and middle shelves went in fine, but the joint on the top shelf was a little too tight and the wood above it cracked. (I had to pound the shelf in with a rubber mallet, which I realize now was a mistake)

I was thinking that I could just cut the tail a little bit looser. It is very dry right now, and I was wondering if when it gets humid in the summer, will the expansion of the tail cause the top to crack off again?

The wood I'm using is white pine.

The dovetail is 1/4 inch deep.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I live in Maine, and my house does not have air conditioning in the Summer, so there are considerable swings in humidity throughout the year.

I don't have a heated shop, so I made the book case outside. The cracking happened as soon as I pounded the shelf in, not after bringing the shelf inside.

Comment: It's perfectly OK to have to bash in a housed shelf within reason, if a shelf slides in fully just with hand pressure it actually indicates they're too loose (in which case you should probably use epoxy as your adhesive of choice if strength is important). Anyway, that aside, I think we could do with a photo to be sure of what you're dealing with, or at least a quick sketch showing the grain directions of the parts and the stock thicknesses. Re. expansion of the tail in the summer, normally the increase (or decrease) in thickness of shelves is so tiny that it is ignored.

Comment: @Graphus I added some photos. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, those are hugely useful! This is minor enough that I'd glue back in place (obviously with clamp pressure in both directions) and not give it another thought. Depending on how you intend to finish it might be worth treating the entire end-grain surface with your glue to even up the colour from the unavoidable excess glue. If you're painting or using a darker "gel stain" then it shouldn't matter though.

Comment: Nice job on the shelves BTW, they look good and straight and extra kudos for using dovetail housing joints.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks! And thank you for your help.